# Add css to Shiny's HTML tag

Tags: r, shiny

I want the text in an HTML tag to be different sizes and red.
In this code, the different sizes works, but the red does not.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML("<p style=font-size:28px; font-color:red;>Hello</p><p style=font-size:22px>There</p>"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `color:red` instead of `font-color:red` and it has to be before the `font-size` tag.
This is the corrected code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML("<p style=color:red;font-size:28px; >Hello</p><p style=font-size:22px>There</p>"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```